# Saving several EditTexts in one activity efficiently with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I found answers to similar questions but none worked for me.
Q1: [Saving several EditText after program closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946434/saving-several-edittext-after-program-closes)
Q2: [Save latest text from Edittext and restore it after onDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148717/save-latest-text-from-edittext-and-restore-it-after-ondestroy)

In my case, we're talking about ~50 EditTexts. With question Q2 I figured how to save one single EditText but as soon as I copy the code for different EditTexts (and use different parameters) when restarting every EditText shows the same word.

```
public static final String LAST_TEXT1 = "";
public static final String LAST_TEXT2 = "";
public EditText myEditText1, myEditText2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

    myEditText1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText1);
    final SharedPreferences pref1= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    myEditText1.setText(pref.getString(LAST_TEXT1, ""));
    myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            pref.edit().putString(LAST_TEXT1, s.toString()).commit();


        }
    });

    myEditText2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText2);
    final SharedPreferences pref2= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    myEditText2.setText(pref.getString(LAST_TEXT2, ""));
    myEditText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            pref.edit().putString(LAST_TEXT2, s.toString()).commit();


        }
    });
}
```

Basically, this several times with all the parameters changed. (pref, myEditText,LAST_TEXT) But all the different EditTexts (like myEditText1 and myEditText2) would on the restart then show the same word.

Is there any efficient way to save all these contents?
Would there be a better way to save Strings in a table (I'm a beginner)
If there is no "efficient" way to save all these EditTexts how can I change my code so that it would save the data right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the edittexts inside and recyclerView or gridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you are using same key for all `EditText` and that's what it's giving you back:

```java
public static final String LAST_TEXT1 = "";
public static final String LAST_TEXT2 = "";
```

Here `LAST_TEXT1` and `LAST_TEXT2` are equals. `SharedPreferences` are key/value based storage option. If you want to save different values for all your editexts, use different keys. And I'd recommend, not empty Strings.

You can also use one key and store an object containing all your edittexts values structured the way you want, the way you should be able to retrieve data easily, for example using JSONArray and stringify it.

The content of `EditText2` will replace the content of `EditText1` in your preferences since you are using the same key.

And when you try to retrieve your content, the associated value of `""` will be shown. `LAST_TEXT1` and `LAST_TEXT2` are just variables here. Keys are what is contained within the variable.

I hope this will help.

Comment: You're right, the key is the error here. I will take a look at JSONArray then, thanks for the hint! For now editing the keys will do, so thanks.

Comment: Great! Do not hesitate to ask more informations or post other questions in case you have an issue

Answer (score 0):

1.`SharedPreference` saves data in key-value pair. You save a data for a key and when needed, use that same key to recover the value, even if the app is closed.

In your case, you are using two variables for storing string-keys, named, `LAST_TEXT1` and `LAST_TEXT2`. **But sadly, both are carrying the same value**, "" or empty string. As both keys are technically the same, you are getting the same result. Define Those two keys like this to get different results:

```
public static final String LAST_TEXT1 = "LAST_TEXT1";
public static final String LAST_TEXT2 = "LAST_TEXT2";
```

2.`SharedPreference` is used for simple and short key-values. If your values are longer than few words, I suggest using Sqlite Database or similar long time data persisting methods.